# How to deal with Rating system (android + mysql)

Tags: android, rating, ratingbar, rating-system

I want to use a rate system in my app , well I know how to implement `RatingBar`  but I need to know the way I can calculate rating after each rate 
For example user 1 give 5 starts but 2 other users gives 3 , 4 starts, so what is the result in this case and how to calculate it ? there is a formula of calculation for this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you have to show the average rating

the formula is (sum of all ratings)/(count of total rating)

example 4 user give rating 1,2,3,5 respectively.
then your formula be like
(1+2+3+5)/4
answer will be 2.75

Comment: but in my table user there is 1 column of rating so i think i should calculate rating after each rate ?

Comment: no you have to put a query and code to calculate the average rating.

Comment: but how ?? for example the first user gived 5 stars i will store in the column 'rating' the value of 5 stars , the second user gived 2 stars and here i should update the column rating to get the new rating .. well for this example there is 2 users but in the real time i can't konw how much users even if i create a new table with id user1,id_user2,rate that's it ??

Comment: you have to keep all the ratings with user id.
 create 2 colums only user_id & user_rating.

Answer (score 0):

If you have separate SQL tables for User and Ratings as `tblUser` and `tblRatings` respectively.

```
SELECT username, AVG(stars) AS average_rating
FROM tblUser
INNER JOIN tblRatings USING(mUserId)
GROUP BY mUserId
ORDER BY average_rating DESC, title;
```

Give your feedback if it helped of not. Happy to help more.

Comment: I need to create the table Rating , thank you for your help

Comment: if it helped then you can upvote and accept answer. thanks.